# My 2 year 8 month old son is not interested in hearing stories

Tags: toddler, language-development, speech

How to make child get interested in stories? He colors the book but by seeing somewhere. He just shows interest in only very limited food. He is suffering from constipation. He is able to say rhymes, alphabets, number, shapes... But is not able to answer simple questions. For example: Have you completed your lunch? What did you eat? What did you learn in your school? Just started his preschool from June 2018. Little worried why he is not able to understand what we are speaking and not answering to us. How can I improve him? He is completing 3 by December.

Comment: "What did you learn at school?" is not a simple question. A child will do a lot of things during the day at school, and summarizing all that into a single sentence is actually a very difficult skill.

Comment: Because these symptoms are physical more than behavioural, these are questions that you should be asking your doctor. If your doctor isn't concerned, you needn't be concerned.

Comment: You have a few questions in there, which may not be related. Can you please edit to focus on one, otherwise you may continue to get close votes.

Answer (score 3):

Kids develop at different rates and that rate will vary throughout their life. There are long periods when a kid seems to be "stuck" and then they will zoom forward.

One piece of  good news is that a pre-school which is properly regulated will certainly be on the look-out for **developmental issues** and they have both the training and many children to see how they are doing. If you are worried, your preschool may be able to help. In many countries preschools are regulated by the education regulator and are very alert to these things. The suggestion of a doctor is also good, but doctors can be expensive or difficult to access, and many general practitioners are oblivious to this specialist area, anyway. You are already paying the preschool, they will be able to tell you whether or not it's worth medical attention.

Most 2-3 year old kids won't be **interested in books** as objects (except for the pictures). They can be interested in stories, and you reading them out in an interesting way and may well become interested in books and so reading as a result of that, but that will take time. It's important to distinguish interest in (eg oral) stories (which is worth pushing) from books (which will follow).

**Questions about summarizing** seem to come very late for children. It can seem like disinterest which can be frustrating, but it's a difficult skill which involves lots of things like good episodic memory, the ability to form stories for others, empathy, etc. My son is five and it's just about getting there. One way in is to try to glean as much as possible about specifics at the school and to try to ask specific questions. *"Did you do any singing at school today?"*, *"Do you sit near Jack at school?"*. This will probably start out as random stabs in the dark, but you must proceed like a spy, gathering pieces of information (from your child, newsletters, etc) to build a picture. In the end, you can get more and more specific and it will slowly fall into place. This is important to do, as it really builds a relationship.

It's also worth saying **why you are asking**. A kid doesn't know why you want to know which I suppose, like most of us, is because you are interested in the child's life, and you want to know what they like and dislike so that you can make their life more pleasant by doing more of what they like. It's worth telling your child this (it may not go in at first) because it really helps them be forthcoming in the end.

I think the priorities with two and three year olds are usually about setting boundaries for behaviour and also (which they will find more pleasant) letting them do more and more, daily routine, helping out, pretending, etc, which they seem to find exciting. Three years old is the last time in your life that helping with the washing up is exciting!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to me like this it's pretty normal for a not quite three year old, within the limits of a brief description on the internet. If you are concerned that he might have some sort of learning disability, your pediatrician or family doctor would be the best place to start, and early intervention is important if they confirm any issues.